# Use #frame driver from python API

Tags: python, drivers, shader-nodes

I material nodes it is possible to use `#frame` as value in `Value` node. But when I try to do it from python API

```
bpy.data.node_groups['XXX'].nodes['Value'].outputs['Value'].default_value = '#frame'
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: NodeSocketFloat.default_value expected a float type, not str
```

How can I make this work with python?

Answer (score 1):

```
d = bpy.data.node_groups['WorldRandPerFrame'].nodes['Value'].outputs['Value'].driver_add('default_value')
d.driver.expression = 'frame'
```